# React-Native BlueConic library gives build error on iOS with error could not find __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDataDetection

Tags: ios, react-native

When I tried to implement the [BlueConic SDK for React-Native](https://support.blueconic.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033450654-BlueConic-SDK-for-React-Native) for iOS with XCode, I got the following error:

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swift_Concurrency'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftWebKit'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftFileProvider'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDataDetection'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDataDetection", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDataDetection_$_BlueConicClient in libBlueConicClient.a(AdvancedEvent.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDataDetection_$_BlueConicClient in libBlueConicClient.a(BlueConicCookieStorage.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDataDetection_$_BlueConicClient in libBlueConicClient.a(BlueConicEventFactory.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDataDetection_$_BlueConicClient in libBlueConicClient.a(BlueConicEventManager.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDataDetection_$_BlueConicClient in libBlueConicClient.a(ClickEvent.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDataDetection_$_BlueConicClient in libBlueConicClient.a(UpdateContentEvent.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDataDetection_$_BlueConicClient in libBlueConicClient.a(Event.o)
      ...
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDataDetection_$_BlueConicClient)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftWebKit", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftWebKit_$_BlueConicClient in libBlueConicClient.a(AdvancedEvent.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftWebKit_$_BlueConicClient in libBlueConicClient.a(BlueConicCookieStorage.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftWebKit_$_BlueConicClient in libBlueConicClient.a(BlueConicEventFactory.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftWebKit_$_BlueConicClient in libBlueConicClient.a(BlueConicEventManager.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftWebKit_$_BlueConicClient in libBlueConicClient.a(ClickEvent.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftWebKit_$_BlueConicClient in libBlueConicClient.a(UpdateContentEvent.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftWebKit_$_BlueConicClient in libBlueConicClient.a(Event.o)
      ...
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftWebKit_$_BlueConicClient)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider_$_BlueConicClient in libBlueConicClient.a(AdvancedEvent.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider_$_BlueConicClient in libBlueConicClient.a(BlueConicCookieStorage.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider_$_BlueConicClient in libBlueConicClient.a(BlueConicEventFactory.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider_$_BlueConicClient in libBlueConicClient.a(BlueConicEventManager.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider_$_BlueConicClient in libBlueConicClient.a(ClickEvent.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider_$_BlueConicClient in libBlueConicClient.a(UpdateContentEvent.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider_$_BlueConicClient in libBlueConicClient.a(Event.o)
      ...
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider_$_BlueConicClient)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an empty Swift File to your project's app directory in iOS (in the same directory as the `AppDelegate.m` file). It is not necessary to create a Bridging File Header.

This could be the swift file content.

```swift
//
//  File.swift
//

import Foundation

// Added this for the sake of a BlueConic compile error.
```

That's it, problem gone.